# Protected absolute/relative filepath types

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering if there is a library that provides newtype protected FilePath types somewhere.  I found what I want http://hackage.haskell.org/package/darcs-2.8.4/docs/src/Darcs-RepoPath.html, but I hardly want to add darcs as a dependency to all my projects.  Should I copy and paste this module out of darcs and start maintaining a new package on hackage? Does another library already exist?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pathtype may come close to fitting the bill.

Answer (score 0):

How about `FilePath` from [`Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.8/docs/Filesystem-Path-CurrentOS.html) in [`system-filepath`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.8)?

They are not newtype'd so if you really need that efficiency I think you are on your own, but otherwise it looks like a great package.

Comment: I want to have type level guarantees(or at least promises) that a path is absolute/relative.  I want to be able to look at a type signature for a function and know that I'm working with absolute paths(or know that I'm working with relative ones.  How does this get me there?

Comment: @timthelion Oh, I'm sorry. I did not pick up that additional requirement from your OP. My suggestion does not give you that, true.